# Windows bootloader is not recognized after installing Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, windows-11

I had previously tested this dual boot on an older legacy BIOS PC, and it worked fine. I have a new Dell Precision 3660 with UEFI BIOS, with 2 x 1TB NVMe drives. It came with Windows 11 installed, and I installed Ubuntu on the spare drive and it went fine. From BIOS, when I select Windows bootloader it starts to boot Windows, but just sits with the spinning wheel and never actually boots into Windows.The Windows 11 partition is still there, but I just need to get the bootloader to recognize it.

Here is the link to the [pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/n2HHD28fb3/) from Boot-Repair.

```
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/6.1.0-1028-oem
Please backup your data before this operation.

** (gedit:16413): WARNING **: 09:46:45.006: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported
Please backup your data before this operation.

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi of
nvme1n1p3,
using the following options:  nvme1n1p2/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed:  unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file restore-efi-backups


rm /boot/efi/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
mv /boot/efi/efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /boot/efi/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
/dev/nvme1n1p3/boot/efi not empty

=================== Reinstall the grub-efi of /dev/nvme1n1p3 ===================

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.06-2ubuntu7.2
modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/6.1.0-1028-oem
modprobe efivars

efibootmgr -v before grub install
BootCurrent: 0006
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0006,0007,0004,0000,0005,0008,0001,0002,0003
Boot0000* UEFI RST PM9A1 NVMe Samsung 1024GB S6H2NF0WC10154     HD(1,GPT,fc164da3-a5e9-4cba-8005-2f2356d5d139,0x800,0x64000)/File(EFIBootBootX64.efi)N.....YM....R,Y.
Boot0001* ONBOARD NIC (IPV4)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(cc96e53d680c,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)N.....YM....R,Y.
Boot0002* ONBOARD NIC (IPV6)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(cc96e53d680c,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)N.....YM....R,Y.
Boot0003* UEFI HTTPs Boot (MAC:CC96E53D680C)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(cc96e53d680c,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)/Uri()N.....YM....R,Y.
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,672cecf3-5380-4d72-b7df-924ea998ed43,0x40800,0x100800)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0005* UEFI RST PM9A1 NVMe Samsung 1024GB S6H2NF0WC10134     HD(2,GPT,672cecf3-5380-4d72-b7df-924ea998ed43,0x40800,0x100800)/File(EFIBootBootX64.efi)N.....YM....R,Y.
Boot0006* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,fc164da3-a5e9-4cba-8005-2f2356d5d139,0x800,0x64000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0007* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,fc164da3-a5e9-4cba-8005-2f2356d5d139,0x800,0x64000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...;................
Boot0008* UEFI USB SanDisk 3.2Gen1 050171b9df8f4717fbb4f29c1ad897ea2ff51a7fa2356c07e8830421a33cdc95fa8800000000000000000000c49df18aff900510815581077a2ac760 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(19,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x4149c3e0,0x800,0x1caf800)/File(EFIBootBootX64.efi)N.....YM....R,Y.

uname -r
6.1.0-1028-oem

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/nvme1n1p2
mv /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
df /dev/nvme0n1p1
mv /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

efibootmgr -v after grub install
BootCurrent: 0006
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0007,0000,0005,0008,0001,0002,0003
Boot0000* UEFI RST PM9A1 NVMe Samsung 1024GB S6H2NF0WC10154     HD(1,GPT,fc164da3-a5e9-4cba-8005-2f2356d5d139,0x800,0x64000)/File(EFIBootBootX64.efi)N.....YM....R,Y.
Boot0001* ONBOARD NIC (IPV4)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(cc96e53d680c,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)N.....YM....R,Y.
Boot0002* ONBOARD NIC (IPV6)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(cc96e53d680c,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)N.....YM....R,Y.
Boot0003* UEFI HTTPs Boot (MAC:CC96E53D680C)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(cc96e53d680c,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)/Uri()N.....YM....R,Y.
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,672cecf3-5380-4d72-b7df-924ea998ed43,0x40800,0x100800)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0005* UEFI RST PM9A1 NVMe Samsung 1024GB S6H2NF0WC10134     HD(2,GPT,672cecf3-5380-4d72-b7df-924ea998ed43,0x40800,0x100800)/File(EFIBootBootX64.efi)N.....YM....R,Y.
Boot0007* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,fc164da3-a5e9-4cba-8005-2f2356d5d139,0x800,0x64000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...;................
Boot0008* UEFI USB SanDisk 3.2Gen1 050171b9df8f4717fbb4f29c1ad897ea2ff51a7fa2356c07e8830421a33cdc95fa8800000000000000000000c49df18aff900510815581077a2ac760 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(19,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x4149c3e0,0x800,0x1caf800)/File(EFIBootBootX64.efi)N.....YM....R,Y.

update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/oem-flavour.cfg'
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-1028-oem
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-1028-oem
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-1008-oem
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-1008-oem
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme1n1p3/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the The OS now in use - Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS entry (nvme1n1p2/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file) !


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme1n1.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg 
                       /efi/dell/SOS/bootmgfw.efi /efi/dell/SOS/bootmgr.efi 
                       /efi/dell/SOS/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme1n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme1n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

nvme1n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on nvme1n1p3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: GA106 [GeForce RTX 3060 Lite Hash Rate] Intel Corporation from NVIDIA Corporation Intel Corporation
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-1028-oem root=UUID=2f987cda-c40c-4194-a8a0-69a12e78aac0 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
df -Th / : /dev/nvme1n1p3 ext4  938G   12G  878G   2% /

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 2.10.1(2.10) from Dell Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this installed-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0006
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0007,0000,0005,0008,0001,0002,0003
Boot0000* UEFI RST PM9A1 NVMe Samsung 1024GB S6H2NF0WC10154     HD(1,GPT,fc164da3-a5e9-4cba-8005-2f2356d5d139,0x800,0x64000)/File(\EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi)N.....YM....R,Y.
Boot0001* ONBOARD NIC (IPV4)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(cc96e53d680c,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)N.....YM....R,Y.
Boot0002* ONBOARD NIC (IPV6)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(cc96e53d680c,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)N.....YM....R,Y.
Boot0003* UEFI HTTPs Boot (MAC:CC96E53D680C)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(cc96e53d680c,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)/Uri()N.....YM....R,Y.
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,672cecf3-5380-4d72-b7df-924ea998ed43,0x40800,0x100800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0005* UEFI RST PM9A1 NVMe Samsung 1024GB S6H2NF0WC10134     HD(2,GPT,672cecf3-5380-4d72-b7df-924ea998ed43,0x40800,0x100800)/File(\EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi)N.....YM....R,Y.
Boot0007* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,fc164da3-a5e9-4cba-8005-2f2356d5d139,0x800,0x64000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...;................
Boot0008* UEFI USB SanDisk 3.2Gen1 050171b9df8f4717fbb4f29c1ad897ea2ff51a7fa2356c07e8830421a33cdc95fa8800000000000000000000c49df18aff900510815581077a2ac760 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(19,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x4149c3e0,0x800,0x1caf800)/File(\EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi)N.....YM....R,Y.

64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
a1da253696a304dce6b4668b70151c0e   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bootx64.efi
a9c517741ac31962d7feb152948ad1ee   nvme0n1p1/Boot/fbx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   nvme0n1p1/Boot/mmx64.efi
a1da253696a304dce6b4668b70151c0e   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
433224d074127c34064dfa0d732a9977   nvme0n1p1/dell/SOS/bootmgfw.efi
32f69782c9966aee03f44d5ec4ad6711   nvme0n1p1/dell/SOS/bootmgr.efi
433224d074127c34064dfa0d732a9977   nvme0n1p1/dell/SOS/bootx64.efi
2d20ed0d3e457a66b52486dbc47f90a8   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
592685834cbb082c044d21845b0ba7ed   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme1n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme1n1p3   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p5   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p4   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme1n1p2   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme1n1p3   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p5   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme1n1p2   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme1n1p3   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme1n1
nvme0n1p5   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme1n1p2   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme1n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: 71B0C094-4AD4-4BC5-8FCB-755646F50A4B
              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1       2048     411647     409600   200M EFI System
nvme0n1p2     411648     673791     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3     673792 1995229183 1994555392 951.1G Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p4 1995229184 1997256703    2027520   990M Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p5 1997258752 2000377855    3119104   1.5G Windows recovery environment
Disk nvme1n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: EBD1DE18-0E82-47E2-8805-0E83CDC0AF8A
           Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme1n1p1    2048     264191     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
nvme1n1p2  264192    1314815    1050624   513M EFI System
nvme1n1p3 1314816 2000408575 1999093760 953.2G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1:1024GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:PM9A1 NVMe Samsung 1024GB:;
1:1049kB:211MB:210MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:211MB:345MB:134MB::Microsoft reserved partition:hidden, msftres;
3:345MB:1022GB:1021GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftres;
4:1022GB:1023GB:1038MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;
5:1023GB:1024GB:1597MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;
nvme1n1:1024GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:PM9A1 NVMe Samsung 1024GB:;
1:1049kB:135MB:134MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
2:135MB:673MB:538MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
3:673MB:1024GB:1024GB:ext4::;

Free space >10MiB: ______________________________________________________________

nvme0n1: 976747MiB:976762MiB:15.3MiB

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
nvme0n1                                                                                                    
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     AE76-8E7F                            fc164da3-a5e9-4cba-8005-2f2356d5d139 ESP         EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                               22d3d48b-df43-40e7-9e7a-9859db83114c             Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs     A65278BA52789133                     11760dd7-736c-4c04-b7f4-095eb611d244 OS          Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     389835D49835917C                     630fd610-a3b3-4c82-9229-f5aab01dc899 WINRETOOLS  
└─nvme0n1p5 ntfs     ACB0307EB03050D6                     cc004fda-08bd-4dcd-ade1-d5ae33c59b9a DELLSUPPORT 
nvme1n1                                                                                                    
├─nvme1n1p1                                               c0f08ec9-627e-4255-8b88-b7026a53978c             Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme1n1p2 vfat     F352-51FC                            672cecf3-5380-4d72-b7df-924ea998ed43             EFI System Partition
└─nvme1n1p3 ext4     2f987cda-c40c-4194-a8a0-69a12e78aac0 158c46a0-12db-41eb-b5ca-07e06a6250da UBUNTU      

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                     Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1                       62.6M  68% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p4                      262.3M  74% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/nvme0n1p5                      494.2M  68% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5
/dev/nvme1n1p3                      877.5G   1% /

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/nvme0n1p1                      vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme0n1p4                      fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p5                      fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme1n1p3                      ext4            rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 2f987cda-c40c-4194-a8a0-69a12e78aac0 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme1n1p2/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 2f987cda-c40c-4194-a8a0-69a12e78aac0 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme1n1p3/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   2f987cda-c40c-4194-a8a0-69a12e78aac0
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme0n1p1)   osprober-efi-AE76-8E7F
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
Restore OS to factory state

======================== nvme1n1p3/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme1n1p3 during installation
UUID=2f987cda-c40c-4194-a8a0-69a12e78aac0 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=F352-51FC  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1

==================== nvme1n1p3/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

================= nvme1n1p3: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 384.500267029 = 412.854018048  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 288.482429504 = 309.755650048  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
 464.528949738 = 498.784161792  boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-1008-oem                    1
 288.482429504 = 309.755650048  boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-1028-oem                    1
 464.528949738 = 498.784161792  boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
 480.626949310 = 516.069257216  boot/initrd.img                                3
 384.450866699 = 412.800974848  boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-1008-oem                 1
 480.626949310 = 516.069257216  boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-1028-oem                 3
 384.450866699 = 412.800974848  boot/initrd.img.old                            1

=================== nvme1n1p3: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Apr 15  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Apr 15  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14387 Dec 18  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Apr 15  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Apr 15  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Feb 19  2022 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr 15  2022 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr 15  2022 41_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1376 Jan 23 10:07 99_dell_recovery

=============== nvme1n1p3/etc/grub.d/99_dell_recovery (filtered) ===============

#!/bin/bash -e
source /usr/lib/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib
cat << EOF
menuentry "Restore OS to factory state" {
        search --no-floppy --hint '(hd0,gpt3)' --set --fs-uuid A65278BA52789133
        set uuid_options="uuid=A65278BA52789133"
        if [ -s /factory/common.cfg ]; then
            source /factory/common.cfg
        else
            set options="boot=casper automatic-ubiquity noprompt quiet splash nomodeset nopersistent"
        fi
        if [ -s /factory/post-rts-gfx.cfg ]; then
            source /factory/post-rts-gfx.cfg
        fi
        if [ -s /factory/post-rts-wlan.cfg ]; then
            source /factory/post-rts-wlan.cfg
        fi
        #Support starting from a loopback mount (Only support ubuntu.iso for filename)
        if [ -f /ubuntu.iso ]; then
            loopback loop /ubuntu.iso
            set root=(loop)
            set options="iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu.iso \$options"
        fi
        if [ -n "\${lang}" ]; then
            set options="locale=\$lang \$options"
        fi
        if [ -s /factory/dual_enable ]; then
            set options="dell-recovery/dual_boot=true \$options"
        fi
        kernel=/casper/vmlinuz
        if [ ! -f $kernel ]; then
            kernel=/casper/vmlinuz.efi
        fi
        linux   \$kernel dell-recovery/recovery_type=hdd \$uuid_options \$options
        initrd  /casper/initrd
}
```

Comment: After finding out about os-prober and 22.04, I modified the grub loader file and updated it, and it now sees the WIndows install from the Grub loader. However, it fails to boot into WIndows 11 and sits with the spinning circle.

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. Windows also must not be hibernated and fast startup sets hibernation flag. If you cannot boot Windows from UEFI boot mode, then it is a Windows issue. Does F8 get you to a Windows repair console. My Dell needed new motherboard. First time both Windows & Ubuntu worked. But needed second and only fix that worked was total restore from Dell recovery which erased everything & made system just as purchased. Lost Windows apps I installed & Ubuntu totally gone. But Ubuntu was a copy of desktop, so easy to restore & I had another copy on external SSD which I also use.

Comment: Windows itself was fine. Installing Ubuntu seems to have changed the boot loader and a Windows 11 start up repair doesn't see the Windows installation to repair it, but it is there. The Grub loader found the Windows reference and added it to the loader, but it starts to boot Windows but doesn't fully get there.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it wasn't booting due to the motherboard being in RAID mode. It would go so far but fail to load windows because it couldn't see the drive partition. That's also why the boot repair option from the W11 USB could not see the Windows installation to repair it.

I found this solution on a Dell forum from someone who had the same issue. Change the motherboard from RAID to AHCI solved the problem.

All good now, with Windows 11 and Ubuntu available from the boot loader.

Thanks for your response @oldfred