# Windows boot black screen after partion and install of Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 22.04, windows, grub-efi

I have a MacBook Pro (13,2) that underwent a physical malfunction that didn't allow me to run OSX anymore as it was stuck in an error (touchbar lost all connect).

I then wiped the whole computer and switch between Linux Mint and Windows via Rufus (like complete fresh OS installs) for a couple weeks to see which I liked better and all was fine and opted for Windows 11 as school started and it was easy.

For a course I am taking we have to have Ubuntu for some reason and I have done this before, but not to use for dual booting.

After installing Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager everything seemed OK. Then I tried to boot into Windows, but I only got a black screen. I am not sure if this is because I receive an error in GParted about my `/dev/nvme01p2` is throwing a warning or if OS-prober from grub is not seeing the proper bootloader as I ran Boot-Repair and it mentions.

OS1: The OS now in use  - Ubuntu 22.04.3
OS2: Windows 8 or 10 on nvme0n1p3

but the Windows boot loader it attaches to says `/dev/nvme0n1p1@/boot/` .

I'm kind of at a loss as I have spent the last two days trying various ideas from forums.

GParted errors:

[image: gparted error]

[image: gparted info]

Comment: "For a course [...] ubuntu": It would be easier to just run Ubuntu in a virtual machine

Comment: True, but it would be too slow on this system I am using for my needs. I felt I could use the ubuntu side for development on my free time/work and windows for strictly school @DanielT

Comment: Do any of these work? https://askubuntu.com/q/217904/1004020 https://askubuntu.com/q/650194/1004020 https://askubuntu.com/q/1492900/1004020 https://askubuntu.com/q/1501142/1004020 ?